# Mocha supertest isn't POSTing data

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

My test looks like:

```
const request = require('supertest-as-promised')
const app = require('../app')

describe("Basic Authentication with JWT", () => {
  it('Should login properly', function () {
    return request(app)
      .post('/login')
      .field('name', 'myname')
      .field('password', 'password')
      .expect(200)
  });
})
```

In my app, I have:

```
  app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
```

When I run the app normally, it gets the information properly. When I run the test, it shows as `{}`

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
 describe("Basic Authentication with JWT", () => {
      it('Should login properly', function () {
        request(app)
                .post('/login')
                .send({
                    name: "test_name",
                    password: "test_password"
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    res.statusCode.should.eql(200);
                    done();
                })
                .catch(done)
      });
    })
```